# AS3 Error 1084 - expecting rightbrace before end of program

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, debugging, syntax-error

I am new to action script an I can't work out why I am getting these errors.

> Error 1084 - expecting rightbrace before end of program

This is all the code that is on the layer the error states. I have read other places that if you have not used the braces correctly you get this error however I have not used them at all.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.Sprite;
stop();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Your posted code is fine. Did you've inserted something ( MovieClips, Buttons) in the stage ? Are you sure that the error is about that code ? ...

Comment: I re-checked the other layer and found an error in one of those despite the debugging console specifically stating it was on the code I have just posted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to use the debugger and you will get the exact line of your error. The error is speaking about a missing `}` ...

Comment: Yes it is working now despite adobes stupid debugger tool!

Comment: Good ... Could you put how did you resolve the problem ? maybe that can help to resolve someone else's problem ...

Comment: I checked the code in the other layers and found the error there.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an **semicolon** at the end of the **second last line**!

Comment: Thanks but I am still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @James: Please don't apply fixes stated in answers; this invalidates them.

Comment: -1, That's 100% wrong because : 1. the error is not about semicolon, 2. the posted code is fine 100%, 3. a missed semicolon in that code can never fire an error.

Answer (score 0):

James, I would recommend that you keep all of your code in accompanying .as file(s) instead of timeline layers within the .fla file.

There are a lot of tutorials online and on youtube on how to get started with a new document in Flash. In short, when you open a new AS3.0 file also create a new .as file, name them BOTH the same name. Then in the .fla file, under document properties, in the 'Class:' bar input the SAME name of the .as/.fla file (without the .as, just the name).

Then, write all of your code in the .as file starting with 'package' and on and on from there. As you create new MovieClips etc. that need code, make them refer to other .as files with your code.

It's a little investment in learning the basics up front (and believe me, I am still learning a lot of these basics), but this way WILL save you a lot of heartache in the future when trying to tack down spelling or symbol errors. Sometimes the compiler messes up exactly where the missing '}' is or ';' or ')' etc etc etc and if it is in one document instead of floating around in layers here and there it's easier to track down.

My .02 anyhow!
(sorry, new here and can't add this as a comment until my rep is at '50')